# Lua: C++ modules can't reference eachother, undefined symbol

Tags: c++, lua, dynamic-linking, dlopen, undefined-symbol

I've created two modules (shared objects) CPU and SaveState as part of an emulator. Both are independently compiled into .so separate files, and loaded at runtime by a Lua script using require(); i.e.:

```
SaveState = require("SaveState")
CPU = require("CPU")
```

Within CPU, there's a method that operates on a SaveState:

```
int CPU::save_state(SaveState *state) {
    state->begin_section(savestate_namespace, savestate_data_size);

    state->write16(this->reg.af);
    state->write16(this->reg.bc);
    state->write16(this->reg.de);
    state->write16(this->reg.hl);
    state->write16(this->reg.sp);
    state->write16(this->reg.pc);
    state->write8 (this->interrupts_enabled);
    state->write8 (this->irq_flags);
    state->write8 (this->ie_flags);
    state->write8 (this->halted);
    state->write8 (this->halt_bug);
    state->write8 (this->extra_cycles);
    state->write64(this->total_cycles);
    state->write64(this->idle_cycles);

    return SaveState::OK;
}
```

It compiles fine, but the `require("CPU")` line fails:

```
lua5.1: error loading module 'cpu' from file './src/cpu/build/cpu.so':
    ./src/cpu/build/cpu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9SaveState7write64Ey
```

Using `nm -D` I can see that exact symbol in savestate.so, but at runtime it's not seen for some reason.

Comment: Why can't you merge both modules into a single one?

Comment: They're completely separate objects, and SaveState is used by many other modules in the program as well, that will probably all have the same problem.

Comment: You may want to try `package.loadlib`  <http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.loadlib>; especially its `*` form.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, except it's only available in 5.2, whereas I'm using 5.1. That has package.loadlib, but doesn't support the `*` option. I tried just providing a function name and discarding it: `package.loadlib("src/savestate/build/savestate.so", "luaopen_savestate")` (and likewise for CPU), as well as just using `*` anyway (sometimes one version of Lua has a feature that isn't documented until the next version's manual), but it didn't appear to do anything.

Comment: It's suspect that `SaveState::write64` cannot be found whereas the other variants can. Version mismatch? Older version that doesn't support 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this by writing a third module, which gets loaded before the other two and just calls dlopen() in its luaopen_module method:

```
void *res = dlopen("src/savestate/build/savestate.so",
    RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it seems to do the trick. (I'll have to generalize it a bit to not use hardcoded paths and so on...)